# How to remove the background of Layout completely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my main Activity i have created a`FrameLayout`. I have added a `Button` and a `Background Image` it it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/top_header"
    >

<Button
  android:layout_width="25dp"
  android:layout_height="25dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/btn_openDrawer"
  android:background="@drawable/more"
  android:layout_gravity="center|left"
  />
 </FrameLayout>
```

In multiple fragments i am using this header.

But in one of the Fragment, I only need button without background image.

I have tried almost everything from `opacity` to `alpha(0)` but in every case it does not take away the space taken by `Frame Layout`. It starts displaying `white transparent` color when i remove or bring opacity down of image.

I want it to take only the space taken by this button  [image] . and put the contents of fragments above it.

Right now it takes `56dp` height, which i defined for `Frame Layout` and starts displaying the contents of `Fragment Layout` after header height, which is `56dp`.

If i change the height of `Frame Layout` to `0dp`, it stops displaying the button on as well.

**Home Activity**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/header_layout"/>
    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</LinearLayout>
//NavigationView...
```

**HomeActivity.Java**

```
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new MainActivity());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;

//This Code is displaying Header With Image

            case R.id.nav_more:
                fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new MoreActivity());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
        }
```

Kindly guide me, I am just stuck into this for more than 8 hours now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set background transparent.

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

First 2 zeros are for transparency.
You can also create `header_layout` dynamically and set its background as needed.

Comment: Thanks, This code adds a white border in the place of image, and still takes the `56dp` height and starts the other layout after `56dp`

Answer (score 1):

in your frame layout instead of  **android:layout_height="56dp"** write **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

Comment: Thanks,  I want the header size to be 56dp, if i define `wrap_content` it will take more height than required.